# profiling firebase cloud-functions dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[The article](https://medium.com/@duhroach/improving-cloud-function-cold-start-time-2eb6f5700f6) mentions about profiling the cloud function dependencies. How profiling can done for firebase cloud functions and Firestore db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you referenced about Cloud Functions includes 3 steps: dependencies trimming, using dependencies cache and lazy loading. All this should also work for Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Firestore profiling is not something that is currently possible, however, you can create a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) about it.